# Fast compression for streaming images

Tags: objective-c, compression, streaming, jpeg

Does anyone know a faster jpeg compression library for development in Objective-C for iOS/OSX? I'm trying to stream a series of images between devices and the built in routine isn't fast enough. Basically it would look like a video on the receiving end, but the origin would be images and I want as little latency as possible. Or is there something better I can use than compressing each frame as jpegs?

Comment: I've written my own JPEG codec which is about the same speed as LIBJPEG-Turbo and it supports symmetric multithreading, so on a MacBook with a hyperthreaded quad core processor, it goes about 5x the speed of a single thread. I'm willing to let you test it, but I didn't plan on making it open source. The same code will use all available threads on an iOS device (2 or 3).

Comment: I'm looking for something I can put in a product that I plan to distribute. So let me know if you'll be willing to share it or make it open source and I'd love to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try iResize for Mac.

I've used it for a while now and is really impressed with it so far! Definitely a good program.

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/13039/iresize

Comment: I mean a library for X-Code to program with